# Unable to recreate plot for anisotropic Gay-Berne potentials from paper

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, molecular-dynamics

I am trying to make a plot of the Gay-Berne potential using Mathematica. I am following [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.441483) and I am trying to recreate Fig. 2. This is figure 2:
[image]

To save time, the equations from the paper are as follows:

The potential energy of interaction is
$$V(u_1,u_2,\mathbf{r})=4\epsilon(u_1,u_2)\left( \left[ \frac{\sigma (u_1,u_2,\mathbf{\hat{r}})}{r} \right]^{12}-  \left[ \frac{\sigma (u_1,u_2,\mathbf{\hat{r}})}{r} \right]^{6}\right) $$
where $\chi = (\sigma_{\parallel}^2-\sigma_{\perp}^2)/(\sigma_{\parallel}^2+\sigma_{\perp}^2)$
and $$\sigma(u_1,u_2,\mathbf{\hat{r}}) = \sigma _0 \left(1- \frac{1}{2}\chi \left \{ \frac{(\mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_1 + \mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_2)^2}{1+\chi(u_1\cdot u_2)} +\frac{(\mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_1 - \mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot u_2)^2}{1-\chi(u_1\cdot u_2)} \right\} \right)^{-1/2}$$
and
$$\epsilon (u_1,u_2) = \epsilon _0 [1-\chi ^2 (u_1\cdot u_2)^2]^{-1/2}$$

This is my Mathematica code for it:

[image]

My orientation vectors $\hat{u_1},\hat{u_2}$ are $v1,v2$ in the above code. What I am trying to recover is the end-to-end potential energy, but clearly, I am not even going below zero. If I try to get the side-by-side potential energy, by writing $v1=\{0,1,0\},v2=\{0,1,0\}$, I get the following plot:

[image]

Where am I going wrong in the reproduction of this potential? Is something incorrect about how I am setting up my parameters?

Comment: Could you upload Figure 2?

Comment: @AlexTrounev no problem, uploaded